# How can I use ADFS with my node js login to authenticate to other logins

Tags: node.js, jwt, adfs

I have a problem. I want to know how I can add and use ADFS in my node js login and authenticate with it to other logins.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [OpenID Connect](https://www.scottbrady91.com/OpenID-Connect/Getting-Started-with-oidc-provider).

You can get the ADFS endpoints via:

Get-AdfsEndpoint | Where-Object { $_.Protocol -like "OpenID Connect *" } | Format-Table

Or you can use [SAML](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-saml).

OpenID Connect is easier.